# Vlookup based on one column but return value based on other column with Max ID using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, return, max, vlookup

[image]

[image]

From 1st file, using vlookup function in excel where I have only Fill ID in second file , how do I get request type based on Max ID (Column name ID) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:D5,
     _ColumnsNeeded, CHOOSECOLS(_Data,1,4),
     @TAKE(SORT(FILTER(_ColumnsNeeded,INDEX(_Data,,3)=F3),,-1),,-1))
```

---

Fundamentally it is one single formula I just tried to break it down in above:

[image]

---

```
=@TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A3:D5,F3=C3:C5),,-1),,-1)
```

---

Or using `VLOOKUP()` with `MAXIFS()` note this doesn't takes into account of duplicate max values:

[image]

---

```
=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(A3:A5,C3:C5,F3),A3:D5,4,0)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### Max From Filtered Data

```
=LET(data,A2:D11,fcol,3,icol,1,rcol,4,
    IFERROR(INDEX(TAKE(SORT(FILTER(data,
        CHOOSECOLS(data,fcol)=F2),icol,-1),1),rcol),""))
```

[image]